# Error 404 while trying to create new Adminhtml page

Tags: admin, adminhtml

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i've created a new extension in which i've added a new tab in the admin panel take a look at the picture.

[image]

Here is what i have in my files.

In: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </models>  
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>  
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <data>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper_Adminhtml_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/adminhtml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <vivassms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
            <title>SMS Center</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <children>
                <sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                    <title>Send SMS</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/magesms_sendsms</action>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                </sendsms>
                <settings>
                    <title>Settings</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/vivas/</action>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </settings>
                <about translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                    <title>About</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/smsnotification_about</action>
                    <sort_order>11</sort_order>
                </about>
            </children>
        </vivassms>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vivassms>
                        <title>SMS</title>
                        <children>
                            <sendsms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                <title>Send SMS</title>
                            </sendsms>
                            <settings>
                                <title>Settings</title>
                                <children>
                                    <smsprofile translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                        <title>Edit user account</title>
                                    </smsprofile>
                                </children>
                            </settings>
                            <about translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                <title>About</title>
                            </about>
                        </children>
                    </vivassms>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivassms translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                                        <title>Vivas SMS</title>
                                    </vivassms>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsNotification/AboutController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_AboutController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{ 
    public function preDispatch() 
    { 
    return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch(); 
    } 

    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->_initAction();
        $i8ee45e0018a32fb1a855b82624506e35789cc4d2 = $this->getLayout()->createBlock( 'Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'my_block_name_here', array('template' => 'vivasindustries/smsnotification/about.phtml') );
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($i8ee45e0018a32fb1a855b82624506e35789cc4d2); $this->renderLayout(); 
    } 
    protected function _initAction() 
    { 
    parent::_initAction(); 
    $this->_setActiveMenu('smsnotification/about') ->_title(Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('About')); 
    return $this; 
    } 
}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/vivasindustries/smsnotification/about.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mage SMS - SMS notification & SMS marketing
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the BSD 3-Clause License
 * It is available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 *
 * @category    Vivas
 * @package     Vivas_smsnotification
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012-2014 Vivas s.r.o. (http://www.mage-sms.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 */
?>
<h2>
<?php 
echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('About'); ?></h2>
<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Mage SMS module 2013-%s, version ', date('Y')).Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('VivasIndustries_SmsNotification')->version; ?></b><br />
<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Copyright © Vivas s.r.o., All rights reserved'); ?><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Supported Magento versions:'); ?></b><?php echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/config/supported')->versions; ?><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Developer:'); ?></b><br /><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Vivas s.r.o.'); ?><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Address:'); ?></b><br /><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('B. Nemcove 767/13'); ?><br /><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('78701 Sumperk'); ?><br />
<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Czech Republic'); ?><br /><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('VAT: CZ29444268'); ?><br /><br /><b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Office Telephone:'); ?></b><br />
<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('+420 581 110 998'); ?><br /><br /><b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('E-mail:'); ?></b><br />

<a href="mailto:<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('sales@Vivas.com'); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('sales@Vivas.com'); ?></a><br />
<a href="mailto:<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('support@Vivas.com'); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('support@Vivas.com'); ?></a><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Web:'); ?></b><br />
<a href="http://<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('www.mage-sms.com'); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('www.mage-sms.com'); ?></a><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Facebook:'); ?></b><br /><iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmagentosms&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;appId=242281502635180" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe><br /><br />

<b><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Manual:'); ?></b><br /><a href="http://<?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('www.mage-sms.com/manual.html'); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('www.mage-sms.com/manual.html'); ?></a><br /><br />
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'smsnotification/Vivas-logo.gif'; ?>" alt="Vivas" />
```

When i try to open the `About` page i got error 404.
Can you please help me fix this error and give me info why i got this problem?

EDIT:
Image of the Error:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main reason I've seen for people getting 404 in the admin is due to not logging out and logging back in (to reload the ACL) after an extension install.

Comment: That is not the reason here. I got 404 at the frontend when i try to open the `About` page. The 404 error is not received in the Admin Panel but in the frontend which i think is awkward..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `config.xml` you didn't close a node.

```
 </smsnotification>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
```

Should be:

```
 </smsnotification>
 </helpers>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
```

And you have the closing helpers tag in the wrong section:

```
 </adminhtml>
   </helpers>
 </global>
```

Should be:

```
 </adminhtml>
 </global>
```

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure why this is in there.  Try removing it:

```
   <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <data>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper_Adminhtml_Data</data>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
```

Also change this in your `adminhtml.xml`:

```
            <about translate="title" module="smsnotification">
                <title>About</title>
                <action>adminhtml/about</action>
                <sort_order>11</sort_order>
            </about>
```

Move: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsNotification/AboutController.php to /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/AboutController.php

Comment: I did what you suggest to me and the error is still here. Any additional advice ?

Comment: Edit your Question with your latest `app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml`

Comment: Done. I've edited my question with the latest config.xml. Please check it out!

Comment: Answer edited.  Try again

Comment: Try changing your adminhtml.xml `<action>` to `adminhtml/about` and drop the smsnotification

Comment: Now i got the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_initAction() in /home/superweb/public_html/store/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/AboutController.php on line 18` the good thing is that the error 404 is gone!!

Comment: Change: `protected function _initAction()` to `public function _initAction()`

Comment: I've done this but the error is still the same.. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20921/discussion-between-seanbreeden-and-the-lex).